# Appium Select Element by ID

Tags: android, appium, seetest

I am trying to convert my [SeeTest](https://experitest.com/test-automation-tool-for-mobile-testing-continuous-integration/) suite to Appium, but I'm having one large issue:

I can't select elements by their `@id` attribute. When I try to select by ID, it says "element not found". When I view the apk through uiautomateviewer, no element `@id`s are visible.

SeeTest requires an apk to be an "instrumented" in order to select by `@id`. Is there any equivalent of "instrumentation" for Appium?

Comment: use `@resource-id` if you use xpath, or  `id` (not `@id`) if you use the `id` locator strategy. In the case of the xpath, though, you need to full id, with package name and `:id/` part.

Comment: @njzk2 no `@resource-id`s are visible in uiautomatorviewer either. I'm using API version 17 (Android 4.2.2) if that is relevant

Comment: the resource-id is simply the id of your view in you xml layout

Comment: @njzk2 http://screencast.com/t/t0LfAxNy9GMh

Comment: not sure what you expect that to do. Use the appium inspector to see the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was because Appium only supports selection by id with Android API level 18+. I was on 17, so I switched to the Selendroid Appium backend.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is that if it does not appear in the Appium inspector, do no use it. What you could do is something along the lines of:

`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//<UIElementType[contains(@<identifier>, '<identifier value>')]>");`

Where identifier can be

- name or content-desc
- label
- text

and a few more.

Hopefully this will help with your changes.

Comment: Well, I have a large automation framework already in place using id's (with SeeTest as the backend). I just want to make Appium behave the same as SeeTest with respect to id's

Comment: name does not work on android. neither does label. Your best bets are resource-id, content-desc, and text.

Comment: I do not have access to my appium code currently but is it possible to find it in the same manner I stated above but using `contains(@resource-id, 'com.package.path.id')`

Otherwise I don't know if there is a way to find in a similar way. Can you possible show me an example of how your SeeTest works. I am unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Like `njzk` stated name will not work, on Android it is known as content-desc however if you are trying to find the attibute `content-desc` you need to use 
`element.getAttribute("name");` where element is of type AndroidElement

Answer (score 0):

```
public void athenaclick(String element) {
    WebElement webElement = driver.findElement(By.id(element));
    webElement.click();
    System.out.println("Click element: "+element);
}
```

In seetest when you instrument you get extra properties which might not be available when in appium eg: text colour as seetest is a paid tool and appium is a open source.